# UIImage resizing too tall in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I added auto layout to my cell and in both `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` i have this:

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

The cell gets even bigger than what it is in storyboard and the UIImageView gets extremely tall like this:

As you can see, the red is the extra space being created and is the background color of UIImageView

[image: As you can see, the red is the extra space being created and is the background color of UIImageView]

Comment: It seems your image size is big. Can you provide link of this image? so i can sort out your problem.

Comment: hmm. i dont have a link to it.

Comment: @Abhijit with any image i have it will have that border on top and bottom and really stretch it, The stretching height ends up bigger than whats on the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

just set constraints from Xcode "pin" tab